# NSManagedObject inserted in context, but not shown in tableview

Tags: core-data, macos-catalina

Using Core Data in my App, I have a strange behaviour. I can add and remove objects using FirstResponder, and the objects are shown immediately in my tableView.
But if I want to add Objects programmatically , objects are only registered and not saved - nor shown in the tableView.

What I did :

Creating the PersistentContainer

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arrayCrtl: NSArrayController!
    var  container: NSPersistentContainer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name:"Document")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error ) in
            if let error = error { print ("\(error)")  }
        })
    }
```

Then, programmatically adding a ManagedObject

```
        let context = container.viewContext
        let describer = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event", in: context)!
        let newEvent:Event = Event(entity:describer, insertInto:context)

       
        container.viewContext.insert(newEvent)
        print ( container.viewContext.registeredObjects)
```

Any idea what's missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to set the ArrayController to "prepares content" in the attribute inspector:
[image]